# Riddle found at my college

Tags: riddle

I'm not sure, just saw it on the wall at UC Berkeley, probably for a competition :

> I am many colors, but I'm not a rainbow.
>
> My skin is the cousin of chess, yet my board is extended.
>
> I am with you here and sometimes at home.
>
> **Who am I?**

What would you all here on puzzling do to tackle a riddle like this?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Is this part of an ongoing competition of some sort?

Comment: Where exactly did you find this puzzle? "I am with you here" might require context on where this puzzle is written/placed in order to make sense.

Comment: Please stop creating new accounts!  You have three already!!

Comment: Do you have tartan drapes in your school by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's:

> **Tiled floors**
>  [image]

I am many colors, but I'm not a rainbow.

> Tiles are not necessarly black and white, they can be of any color.

My skin is the cousin of chess, yet my board is extended.

> Tiled floors resemble chess boards but they are not 8x8 they are much bigger than that (extended)

I am with you here and sometimes at home.

> Tiled floors are everywhere: classrooms, houses (mostly bathrooms and kitchens, hence the *"sometimes"*), ...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on interpretation, you could be a...

> digital screen, such as computer's monitor display.

`I am many colors, but I'm not a rainbow.`

> A screen produces graphics by using many many tiny pixels, which can change color. They form patterns that can represent text, images, and other visuals.

`My skin is the cousin of chess, yet my board is extended.`

> The pixels are organized into a grid, with rows and columns like a chessboard. The word "extended" here could mean "dynamic", in the sense that a pixel can change color.

`I am with you here and sometimes at home.`

> If you can see this (here), then you must be looking at some sort of digital screen. And many homes contain devices with digital screens, such as personal computers.

Answer (score 1):

The answer could be..

> **textbook**

Comment: Seems a good idea for a wide riddle

Answer (score 0):

The answer could be

> 3D chess (from Star Trek)

Explanation

> It is available in many colors. It has chess skin but is extended (3 chess boards.) I don't know if they have it at Berkley, but I have one at my home. So...

Answer (score 0):

The answer could be

> An Ironing Board

Explanation

> At least the one in my house is checkered in its pattern and is longer (or extended in the context of the riddle) than a chess board. They can come in many different colors.

Comment: Please don't create multiple accounts. See https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts for directions on merging them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was

> Carpet

Explanation

> Many colors, can have a checkered pattern, exists both at college and at home.

Answer (score 0):

The answer could be:

> [Halma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halma) or [Chinese checkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_checkers), which is based off of Halma.

I am many colors but I'm not a rainbow.

> Halma has pieces of 4 different colours and Chinese checkers has pieces of 6 different colours.

My skin is the cousin of chess,

> Halma and Chinese checkers have a similarity to checkers (jumping pieces). Halma could be considered the cousin of chess, being played on a similar board. Chinese checkers could either consider Halma or Checkers as its skin; being based off of it for the former and sharing part of its name for the latter.

yet my board is extended.

> Halma fits this better, as it's played on a 16x16 square board instead of a 8x8 board. Chinese checkers also has a larger board, with 121 spaces instead of 64, but the board is in a star shape instead of a square.

I am with you here and sometimes at home.

> The puzzle could have been intentionally posted near a room containing one of these games. Some people might also own these games themselves.
>
>  As mentioned by [D.Krueger](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/57505/riddle-found-at-my-college#comment177066_57528), the spaces that each player starts in is the home and the players' objective is to get all of their pieces in the home of the player opposite them.
>  "With you here" could be referring to the centre part of the board, where all pieces will cross each other.

Comment: You may want to look into the concept of "home" as it relates to your answer(s).

Comment: Oops I just posted the same answer lol, I don’t read spoilers (deleted)

Answer (score 0):

Could you be:

> A puzzle?

I am many colors, but I'm not a rainbow.

> Puzzle can be a picture of many colors.

My skin is the cousin of chess, yet my board is extended.

> Puzzle forms by little pieces like the chessboard, but is extended.

I am with you here and sometimes at home.

> Yes we're at 'Puzzling' right now.  At home...I don't know you always feeling puzzle at home?

Who am I?

> Puzzle